# Javascript image not loading in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, image, google-chrome

I am doing the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">


    <script>
      function LoadImage() {
        var rowCover = document.createElement("img");
        var ImgSRC = "https://marell-av.nl/thumbnails/A/A.jpg"

        rowCover.setAttribute("src", ImgSRC);
        rowCover.setAttribute("style", "margin-left: 5px; margin-right:10px; margin-top: 5px; height:200px; width:200px; float:left");
        //target.appendChild(rowCover);
        document.getElementById('tracks').appendChild(rowCover);
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>


    <div id="tracks"></div>

    <script>
      LoadImage()
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that this image loads fine in firefox, but does not load in chrome or edge. Why?
When I inspect the code in Chrome the link is fine. When I paste the link "https://marell-av.nl/thumbnails/A/A.jpg" in a new tab, the image loads fine.

As a side note I would also like to know  how I can load a placeholder image in case loading fails.

Comment: Suggestion.. rather than creating an element at runtime, it would be better to create in html and hide it unless loading fails

Comment: `ImgSRC` is defined as `imgSRC`. Why not post the acutal code which also shows the appending part? To check if loading fails you have the event [onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror)

Comment: What happens when you try with [this method](https://jsbin.com/zususoyova/edit?js,output)?

Comment: placeholder? read the spec for `alt` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Comment: Is `https://marell-av.nl` the same site as this code?  If so you probably do not need the full URL in there.  If not, it asks for a login when you paste the link.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with the server guys. Somehow moving the images to another folder did the trick. Question remains though why firefox had no issues at all, as opposed to chrome.